# Java-side concurrent access to a JNI/C++ library

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am not able to reproduce the error with some minimal working example because the error involves performing complex read operations within the c++ library. Still, I performed some tests and I can describe the outcome of the two possible configurations.

I have some java code that performs a lookup in files (serialized in a binary format) via a class (namely, JNIClass) accessing a c++ library through JNI.

The JNIClass is used within a Consumer applied to java streams' forEach methods. The streams can be either streams or parallelStreams. I noticed some errors only when such streams are parallel ones, and the c++ library does only perform readings and binary searches over a serialized data structure, and no heap-allocate data structure is allocated. The only thing that is shared among the threads is some function pointer for comparisons for binary search. So, I'm wondering why a readonly operation that returns the lookup result in Java would cause such problems.

I was thinking of a possible solution but I don't know if that is feasible in Java: would decoupling the c++ library and associating each thread to a different library file would solve the memory access problem? Is the sharing.of the aforementioned function pointer for the binary search the source of the problems?

**EDIT**

Core dump (`gdb java core`):

```
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
Core was generated by `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Xmx60g -javaagent:/media/giacomo/Data/Scar'.
Program terminated with signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: File o directory non esistente.
[Current thread is 1 (Thread 0x7f48473ec700 (LWP 8542))]
(gdb) where
#0  __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1  0x00007f57775a1801 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2  0x00007f5776e8e3c5 in os::abort(bool) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007f57770325b3 in VMError::report_and_die() () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007f5776e9470f in JVM_handle_linux_signal () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007f5776e8a653 in signalHandler(int, siginfo*, void*) () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  <signal handler called>
#7  0x00007f48462ffb4d in SLHM_Secondary::searchForId (this=0x7f47640179b8, toSearch="elias delta coding") at /home/giacomo/CLionProjects/edgeindexing/fmatch/StringLongHashMultimapIndexer/SLHM_Secondary.cpp:34
#8  0x00007f4846300c14 in FuzzyMatch_FDContainer::rankCollectionOf (this=0x7f47640179b8, k=std::unordered_set with 368560 elements = {...}, m1=std::unordered_map with 10 elements = {...}, size=10, 
    threshold=0.69999999999999996, pollMap=...) at /home/giacomo/CLionProjects/edgeindexing/fmatch/FuzzyMatch_FDContainer.cpp:123
#9  0x00007f4846301483 in FuzzyMatch_FDContainer::fuzzyMatch (this=0x7f47640179b8, threshold=0.69999999999999996, topk=3, objectString="105th Brigade", result=std::multimap with 0 elements)
    at /home/giacomo/CLionProjects/edgeindexing/fmatch/FuzzyMatch_FDContainer.cpp:181
#10 0x00007f4846301792 in FuzzyMatch_FDContainer::fuzzyMatch (this=0x7f47640179b8, threshold=0.69999999999999996, topk=3, objectStrings="105th Brigade")
    at /home/giacomo/CLionProjects/edgeindexing/fmatch/FuzzyMatch_FDContainer.cpp:213
#11 0x00007f48462e82dc in Java_org_ufl_hypogator_jackb_fuzzymatching_TwoGramIndexerJNI_fuzzyMatch (env=0x7f475c0029f8, self=0x7f48473ead48, dim=0x7f48473ead40, threshold=0.69999999999999996, topk=3, 
    term=0x7f48473ead20) at /home/giacomo/CLionProjects/edgeindexing/fmatch/libfuzzymatch.cpp:48
#12 0x00007f5761018687 in ?? ()
#13 0x00007f48473eac90 in ?? ()
#14 0x00007f484f906ad0 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f48473eacf0 in ?? ()
#16 0x00007f484f9089a8 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Stack information from the `.log` file:

```
Stack: [0x00007f71eb8fd000,0x00007f71eb9fe000],  sp=0x00007f71eb9fa620,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libc.so.6+0x97207]  __libc_malloc+0x197

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Ljava/lang/Class;[B[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass()Ljava/lang/Class;+511
j  java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite()Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;+1
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;+31
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$DMH.invokeStatic_L6_L(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+20
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$BMH.reinvoke(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+79
j  java.lang.invoke.LambdaForm$MH.invoke_MT(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+30
j  java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;+184
j  java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MemberName;+6
j  java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/MemberName;+45
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.scraper.adt.DiGraphEquivalenceClass.loadFromFile2(Ljava/io/File;Lorg/ufl/hypogator/jackb/disambiguation/dimension/concept/ConceptNetVocabulary;Ljava/util/function/Function;)V+11
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.fuzzymatching.TwoGramIndexerJNI$TwoGramIndexerForDimension.<init>(Lorg/ufl/hypogator/jackb/fuzzymatching/TwoGramIndexerJNI;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/ufl/hypogator/jackb/fuzzymatching/TwoGramIndexerJNI;)V+89
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.fuzzymatching.TwoGramIndexerJNI.openDimension(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/ufl/hypogator/jackb/fuzzymatching/TwoGramIndexerJNI$TwoGramIndexerForDimension;+25
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.scraper.MultiConceptScraper$PrivateTermScorer.<init>(Lorg/ufl/hypogator/jackb/scraper/MultiConceptScraper;Ljava/lang/String;Z)V+39
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.scraper.MultiConceptScraper.dimension(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Lorg/ufl/hypogator/jackb/scraper/TermScorer;+7
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.disambiguation.dimension.concept.ConceptNetDimensionDisambiguationOperations.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+57
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.disambiguation.dimension.concept.DisambiguatorForDimensionForConcept.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+2
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.disambiguation.dimension.concept.DimConcepts.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+15
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.inconsistency.legacy.TupleComparator.generateFromType(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/ufl/hypogator/jackb/comparators/partialOrders/InformationPreservingComparator;+117
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.m9.CompareOnce.lambda$memoizeTypeComparisons$2(Lorg/jooq/Record;)V+13
j  org.ufl.hypogator.jackb.m9.CompareOnce$$Lambda$14.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+4
j  java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(Ljava/lang/Object;)V+5
j  java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Ljava/util/function/Consumer;)V+53
j  java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Ljava/util/stream/Sink;Ljava/util/Spliterator;)V+32
j  java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachTask.compute()V+103
j  java.util.concurrent.CountedCompleter.exec()Z+1
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec()I+10
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask;)V+21
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(Ljava/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue;)V+35
j  java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run()V+24
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

The last line is the code for `searchForId` causing the error:

```
void *SLHM_Secondary::searchForId(std::string &toSearch) {
    LONG_NUMERIC hash = hashf(toSearch);
    struct long_index_file toSearchVehicle{};
    toSearchVehicle.id = hash;
    struct long_index_file* ptr = binVectorFixedSizeArray<struct long_index_file>(pimarySparseIndex, primarySize, &toSearchVehicle, &findLongIndexOffset);
    if (ptr == nullptr) return nullptr;
    LONG_NUMERIC* offsets = (LONG_NUMERIC*)(this->element+ptr->offset);
    LONG_NUMERIC n               = offsets[0]; // Line 34
```

Comment: From your description, is not clear what memory access problem you are trying to avoid.

Comment: Sure. The accessed data is memory mapped via c++ library, and the values (longs and strings) are returned respectively as native types and String[]. Which details would clarify my  question?

Comment: Unfortunately, you reply did not make it clear. You *"noticed some errors"*, but what kind of errors? Is the app crashing? Or you see some unexpected answers? And if you do, which answers did you expect to see? Maybe, these errors can be reproduced without JNI (instead of running the true C++ library, emulate its behavior in Java)?

Comment: (See the post edits) Yes, the crash happens at the C++ error as it can be evinced from the post's edit. No, I see no unexpected answers, since I've already debugging the deserialization part of my code. The errors are caused by the multithreaded interaction between Java and C++ library. Without multithreading, no error occurs and everything goes smoothly. Is seems that the error is due to the access to the secondary memory.

Comment: @jackb That sounds like a race condition in your C++ code.

Comment: I know, but in this case I'm just accessing the memory mapped file by reading. The line causing the fault is remarked in the code. How is this possible, a race condition without accessing concurrently any data structure in primary/secondary memory by writing, but only on reading? That is what astonishes me.